# StockTwits Authorisation using API

Tags: stocktwits

I have a problem during authorization on StockTwits using API. When I make a request on

https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize

I receive an HTTP 404 error.
Has anything changed in StockTwits authorization process recently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our service was down temporarily while making updates to some packages. This is now working again.